# Why does awk do different OFS parsing if I zero-out a field?

Tags: awk

Parsing multiline "records" by incrementing a counter on a reliable separator (would use `/^$/` with sed.

Parsing ldif that looks like the following (but I want this to quickly generalize with other record types, e.g. creationTime)

```
dn: uid=asd,ou=People,dc=MY,dc=ORG
objectClass: ...
cn: Adam Saddler
uid: asd 
creationTime: 20110409131545-0700
uidNumber: 1234

dn: uid=mfwth,ou=People,dc=MY,dc=ORG
objectClass: ...
cn: Mike Foksworth
uid: mfwth
creationTime: 20160704144535-0800
uidNumber: 12345
```

And want to be able to generate

```
uid, cn, ...
asd, Adam Saddler, ...
mfwth, Mike Foksworth, ...
```

Where `...` is other fields I want to let `awk` parse, instead of mixing in `gsub`s.

I'm parsing it with

```
$ awk
 -vOFS=';'
 /dn/{ i++ }
 /cn/{ users[i]["cn"]=$0 }
 /uid/{ users[i]["uid"]=$0 }
 END{ for (j in users) print users[j]["uid"] "_" users[j]["cn"] }'
```

and get (where `_` is '_', tab, or space)

```
uid: asd_cn: Adam Saddler
uid: mfwth_cn: Mike Foksworth
```

While, by contrast, modifying the matches before storage `/xx/ { $1="" ; ... }`

```
$ awk
 -vOFS=';'
 /dn/{ i++ }
 /cn/{ $1="" ; users[i]["cn"]=$0 }
 /uid/{ $1="" ; users[i]["uid"]=$0 }
 END{ for (j in users) print users[j]["uid"] " " users[j]["cn"] }'
```

Seems to make the output field separator (OFS) relevant again?

```
;asd; Adam;Saddler
;mfwth; Mike;Foksworth
```

Why does awk output the first one as one block (a string?), but parse and output the second as a series of records?

Comment: Please post correct expected output in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Ed Morton explains it, but if you want to see it in the docs, look for the **Understanding $0** section at the end of this page:  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to any field (e.g. `$1=""` in your 2nd script) specifically tells awk to recompile the current record (`$0`) replacing each `FS` with an `OFS`.

Here's how to really do what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
    next
}
{ prt() }
END { prt() }
function prt(   tagNr,tags,numTags,tag,val) {
    OFS=", "
    numTags = split("uid cn",tags)
    if ( ++numRecs == 1 ) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
uid, cn
asd, Adam Saddler
mfwth, Mike Foksworth
```

Note that the above does not require GNU awk, doesn't store the whole file in memory, doesn't require you to give the explicit tag names in multiple places, lets you simply list the tags you want output in `split("uid cn",tags)`. In fact if you just wanted to print all of the fields as a CSV and didn't want to re-order them for the output and they were all present in every record like in your sample input then you wouldn't need to mention them at all. Here's how to generate a valid CSV (e.g. as could be read into Excel) from such a file of blank-line-separated records with colon-separated tag:values like you've shown in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
    tags[++numTags] = tag
    next
}
{ prt() }
END { prt() }
function prt(   tagNr,tag,val) {
    OFS=","
    if ( ++numRecs == 1 ) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            printf "\"%s\"%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = tag2val[tag]
        gsub(/"/,"\"\"",val)
        printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
    numTags = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"dn","objectClass","cn","uid","creationTime","uidNumber"
"uid=asd,ou=People,dc=MY,dc=ORG","...","Adam Saddler","asd","20110409131545-0700","1234"
"uid=mfwth,ou=People,dc=MY,dc=ORG","...","Mike Foksworth","mfwth","20160704144535-0800","12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract fields after the `=` or `:` character.

This GNU awk script may help you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
      RS="\n\ndn: |,|\n"
      FS="[=:] *"
    }
    NF{a=a (a?",":"")$2}
    RT~/dn:/{print a;a=""}
    END{print a}' file
```

The record separator `RS` is set such that it captures records separated by either `dn:` or `,` or a newline.

The field separator is set to split keywords and values using either `:` or `=`.

The main statement fills the variable `a` with all values. When the `dn:` keyword is found or when it is the end of the file the variable `a` is printed.